# How to change the display font of a file in bbedit?

Tags: bbedit

I have my default font in BBEdit set to Helvetica 12, which is the font I want, but for some reason one of my files is displaying in a different font. How do I change my settings to make that file display in Helvetica? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose "Normalize Options" from the Edit menu, which will return that document's settings to the current values in Editor Defaults; that should do the job.